# How to create a new SharePoint list with data from existing list using PowerShell?

Tags: rest, powershell

For a university project, I have to create a new list with data from existing lists in SharePoint 2013. From my little experience in this field, I would use PowerShell with SharePoint's REST API to get and process the data.
The problem is that I don't have administrator rights for SharePoint and thus can only use clientside technologies.

Since I am a real rookie in PowerShell and REST API, does anyone of you have an idea how to solve this problem or has some code examples that match my problem?

Comment: Do you have permissions to::

1) Manage the Source List..
2) Create a new list in Destination site..

If so, you can save the Source list as a template (with items) and upload it to destination site.. This can be done in the Web interface. No need to execute PowerShell.

Comment: Is the idea to make it a repeatable function.  i.e a process you can repeat on any list?

Answer (score 0):

I have only the permission to view the source list, but not editing. And I can create new lists in the destination site.

And yes, this should be a process, in order to have data from multiple source lists, that gets automatically transmitted to my destination list.